# Array prints different values than expected

Tags: c#, arrays, console, console-application

I have a problem - when I try to declare 3-dimensional array that has 0 value at 0 row and other values method prints different numbers than expected.

It should be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

But program prints:

```
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Here's the code:

```
 //soldiers: 4 food: 10 fun: 8
printx(makeTable(soldiers, food, fun), soldiers, food);
 // ...
static public int[ , , ] makeTable(int soldiers, int food, int fun)
        {
            int[,,] table = new int[soldiers+1, food+1, fun+1];
             for (int i = 1; i <= soldiers; i++)
             {
                for (int j = 0; j <= food; j++)
                {
                table[i, j, 0] = 8;
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
    static public void printx(int[,,] input, int a, int b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(' ');
            for (int j = 0; j <= b; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", input[a, b, 0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I just want to print it without third dimension. Value of input[0,0,0] is 0, so writing method is problem.

Comment: You have wrong `Write`. `Console.Write("{0} ", input[a, b, 0]);` is wrong. You should write `Console.Write("{0} ", input[i, j, 0]);`

Comment: Thank you very much praty, forgive for that stupid mistake! Have a nice day my friend :)

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. Do you want me to include this as answer for you to mark?